# Why getting this tls_socket_read error in Mutt?

Tags: sockets, ssh, ubuntu-14.04, mutt, tls1.2

I get the error in Mutt 1.5.21 (2010-09-15) with large amount (>500) of mails when accessing my mails through SSH in Chromebook but in the server Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-66-generic x86_64):

[image]

which seems to be a known bug about [mutt - TLS packet with unexpected length](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/105736):

> mutt tls_socket_read (a tls packet with unexpected length was received was received.)

Changing `set imap_keepalive=900` higher does not help. 
My $HOME/.muttrc where the alias is corresponding to my real email address:

```
alias masi Masi Lorem <masiipsunloremlorem@gmail.com>

#create folders for sennnt mail#
send-hook . my_hdr Fcc: +.sent_`date +%Y_%B`

set sort=threads
set postponed="$HOME/mail/postponed"

mailboxes "=inbox"
mailboxes "=sent"
mailboxes "=draft"

#^u to open url
macro pager \cu |urlview\n

set imap_keepalive=900 # default 
set timeout=300

## send-hook '~t ^masimasiloremhello@gmail\.fi$' 'my_hdr From: Test Hooooook From Mutt Works if you see me <user@host>'

##### Headers
## main headers
ignore *
unignore From: To: Cc: Subject: Date:
## headers in editor
set edit_headers="yes"


set editor="vim"
set beep_new

set record="$HOME/mail/sent/mails"
set mbox=+mbox

macro index,pager y "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "show incoming mailboxes list"
```

### Fix

I think the update to the latest Mutt version with the patches of 2014 should fix the problem. 
I am testing the upgrade in two servers and I will report if it works.

---

Why this bug is occurring in Mutt?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is Ubuntu specific bug. 
Switch to Debian so you avoid those bugs in the future.